Create a function that takes method name and verify if that method was called
I would like to create a method that can take a method name and verify if method was called. I have implemented the following code block and wanted to investigate if there is a better way to do it
Updated
Based on the comments the function is updated. Feel free to comment to improve the function.
private void Then_WirelessDeviceInvokedMethod(
    ushort unitId, 
    string methodName = null, 
    int expectedCallCount = 1, 
    IReadOnlyList<object> expectedArgs = null)
{
    if (expectedArgs == null)
    {
        expectedArgs = new List<object>();
    }
    var wdm = GetWirelessDeviceMock(unitId);
    Assert.That(wdm, Is.Not.Null);

    uint callCount = 0;
    foreach (var invocation in wdm.Invocations)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.Name == methodName && 
            invocation.Arguments.Count == expectedArgs.Count)
        {
            bool hasSameArgs = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < invocation.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!invocation.Arguments[i].Equals(expectedArgs[i]))
                {
                    hasSameArgs = false;
                    break;
                 }
             }

             if (hasSameArgs)
             {
                 callCount++;
             }
        }
    }

    Assert.That(callCount, Is.EqualTo(expectedCallCount));
}


Why are you passing the method as a string to the test method in the first place? Moq makes it easy to verify calls with mock.Verify(target=>target.MethodToCall(..)). If you don't find anything, it means that either you're using the wrong terms or you're trying to do the wrong thing

Verify accepts an Expression, which in .NET is essentially data. You can store Expressions in a dictionary or array. If you want to create a test that checks multiple method invocations (a highly suspicious test) you can pass the expressions as data instead of the method names

Checking for multiple invocations though is a very bad practice because it means you're trying to verify the implementation of the code instead of the correct outcome of a test. That will break every time you change that implementation, even if the class works.

To adhere: checking for a specific member to be called is testing for the interals of your SuT. Instead of this you can however test for the results of that invocation. So don't assume yous SuT to call into method DoSomething, but instead check if the method was called by checking for its outcome - e.g. change of the SuT's state or whatever.

The question is about how to parameterize the invoked function as an argument. Otherwise I have to rewrite the same method with only replacing the method name in unit test for all method that class has.

What if the method has multiple overloads? This wouldn't work. As suggested before there is already everything in moq you need for this including the check that the method was called with the expected parameters.

@Ralf Assume that there is no overload function in the class.

@Hamza and you don't care with what parameters they have been called? The system sounds so lax to me i doubt that such a unittest does anything more then giving you the opportunity to tell someone "i wrote unittest for this" without having actually helpful unittests. And be aware if you start to write complex infrastructure for testing that code needs there own tests also. So you need to test your test code.

This looks like an XY problem. You may have better chances getting a proper answer if you try to explain what kind of problem you are trying to solve.
